# How to replicate the back button in Apple's iOS 17 Contact app?

Tags: ios, ios17

[image: Screenshot]

In iOS 17 the navigation bar in the contact app has new back and edit buttons with a solid white font and translucent gray background.

Reading through the docs, the closest I've been able to get to this was

```
viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
      barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.close,
      target: self,
      action: backSelector
    )
```

which is close to what I'm looking for, but there is only a SystemItem for close (not back) and the X is transparent rather than white.

How can I use the same nav bar button style Apple uses here in my own app?